# Using Snake Oil Method to Evaluate Sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

$$\sum_k \binom{n+k}{2k} \binom{2k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1+m}$$
This is Problem 8 in "Basic Practice" Section of Concrete Maths by Knuth.

In the book, the answer comes out to be: 
$$ (-1)^n \frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}\binom{m}{n}$$

I want to know how to use generating functions to solve this problem since the original method is quite complicated and uses several clever *tricks* which i want to avoid. I have used the **Snake Oil** method and transformed the sum to:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_k \frac{ \dbinom{2k}{k} \left(\dfrac{-x}{(1-x)^2}\right)^k}{k+1+m} $$

... by using the steps given in Example 2 at pg 122 of Herbert Wilf's book on generating functions.

Now, i am stuck, since i don't know what to do with the $k+1+m$ in the denominator. I also can't deduce whether this problem *can* even be solved by generating functions or not.

Comment: What do we want to show?

Comment: Need to derive a closed form for this sum

Comment: OK, now we also have the closed formula for it. (It is still hard to follow the path, one needs the books, to find the place in them, to see the needed ingredients, type the solution. Lots of effort... Now, for me, i do not know if the solution in Knuth's book used generating series, if not, if there is a hint elsewhere that generating series can be used, if they can be used, than using the above "split" via $1/(1-x)$ - and how the $n+k$ over $2k$ binomial coefficient was rephrased, of course i am missing also the second reference. The variable $k$ starts possibly from $0$.) One way to proceed

Comment: would be to write $$f(y)=\sum_k\binom{2k}ky^k$$ and use $$\int y^m\; f(y)\; dy\ .$$

Comment: If I made no mistake anywhere, it seems $G(t) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\,\binom{2k}k \frac1{k+m+1}\, t^k$ is expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions, so I'm not really sure if you're getting much by going snake oil.

Comment: So cant we use/extract coefficients from hypergeometric functions? If not so, is there some other way to solve the sum without using tricks?

Comment: The answer to "*Is there some other way to solve the sum without using tricks?*" is that that's the whole point of Concrete Mathematics chapter 5: use Zeilberger's algorithm. But I don't think that's the kind of answer you're interested in.

Answer (score 6):

Lets start by manipulating the binomial coefficients
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2k}{k} \binom{n+k}{2k} = \binom{n+k}{k} \binom{n}{k}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now two more tricks .... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n+k}{k} = [x^k]:(1+x)^{k+n} = [x^0] : \frac{(1+x)^{k+n}} {x^k} \\
\frac{1}{k+m+1} = \int_{0}^{1} y^{k+m}  dy 
\end{eqnarray*}
Right now lets attack the sum ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+m+1} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{n+k}{2k} &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+m+1} \binom{n+k}{k} \binom{n}{k} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=& [x^0] \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \int_{0}^{1} y^{k+m} dy\frac{(1+x)^{k+n}} {x^k} \binom{n}{k} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &=&  \int_{0}^{1} [x^0]   y^{m} \left( 1-\frac{y(1+x)} {x} \right)^n (1+x)^n  dy\\
&=&  \int_{0}^{1} [x^n]   y^{m} ( -y +x(1-y) )^n (1+x)^n  dy\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now extract the coefficient of $x^n$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &=&  \int_{0}^{1}  \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j}^2  y^{m} (-y)^{j} \left( 1-y \right)^{n-j}  dy\\
&=&  \sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j \binom{n}{j}^2  \frac{(n-j)!(m+j)!}{(n+m+1)!} \\
 &=&  \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j}\binom{m+j}{j}\\
 &=&  \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!} [x^0]: \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} \frac{(1+x)^{m+j}}{x^j} \\
 &=&  \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!} [x^0]: (1+x)^m \left(1- \frac{(1+x)}{x} \right)^n\\
&=&  \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!} [x^0]: (-1)^n \frac{(1+x)^m}{x^n} \\
&=& (-1)^n \frac{n!m!}{(n+m+1)!}   \binom{m}{n} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Use the Beta function to do the integration
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1} y^{m+j}(1-y)^{n+j}   dy  = \frac{(m+j)!(n-j)!}{(m+n+1)!}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Oh ... & Edited in a $(-1)^j$ that I had missed.

Comment: Looks good now!

Comment: Thank you to Fimpellizieri & Joffan for correcting & editing some mistakes.

Comment: You're welcome. Very nice, out-of-the-box answer by the way.